# Retrieve data from database into a html form

Tags: php, html, sql, prepared-statement

[image]

I have code to retrieve data from a database into a form but it doesnt seem to be working. The code below is my attempt but it doesnt work. Currently, when I click the submit button 'retrieve rose' it does nothing...

```
//if we have no errors, do the SQL
if (!$errors) {   

$latin_name = $_POST['latin_name'];

$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT common_name, variety_name, colour, season_of_interest, hardiness, situation, soil_type,
price, stock_level, fragrance, ultimate_height FROM rosename WHERE latin_name = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssdiss', $latin_name);

if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    echo "<form><input type='text' value='" . $row["common_name"] . "' name='latin_name' />";
    echo "<input type='text' value='" . $row["variety_name"] . "' name='soil_type' /></form>";
    } // i no I need to add more here...
    exit;
}

//put out the footer and then stop the rest of the script from running, so we don't display the rest of the form (this is after the form has been submitted)
require_once('footer.php');
exit;
}

//if we do have errors, show the error message
else {
  echo "<p>".$error_msg."</p>";
}}
?>
```

And here is my form:

```
<h1>Update Rose Item</h1>
  <ul class='register'>
      <li>
  <form action="updaterose.php" id="updaterose" method="post">
  <fieldset id="register">
        <label>Latin Name:<span class="small">Enter a Latin Name</span></label><input      name='latin_name' id='latin_name' type='text' value="<?=(isset($_POST['latin_name'])?  $_POST['latin_name']:"");?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Retrieve Rose" name='retrieverose' /></br></br></br>
</form>
```

Code requested by mariogl

```
  //connect to database
$conn2 = DB2();

  require_once('header_admin.php');

  if (isset($_POST['updaterose'])) 
  {

//detect if we have errors or not
$errors = false;
$error_msg = "Error, please try again";
```

Comment: bind_param('ssssssssdiss', $latin_name); looks VERY strange. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: This bracket doesn't match with any: `} // i no I need to add more here...`

Comment: bind_param('ssssssssdiss', $latin_name); is using prepared statements, do you know about prepared statements?

Comment: I haven't used mysqli, but seems like you should only pass one parameter (as you have only one question mark), and you're passing 12.

Comment: When you click the submit button, it does nothing or does it load the page and then does nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the first condition, you're asking for a variable named "updaterose", that doesn't exist. Try this:

```
  if (isset($_POST['retrieverose'])) 
  {

    //detect if we have errors or not
    $errors = false;
    $error_msg = "Error, please try again";

    //if we have no errors, do the SQL
    if (!$errors) {   

        $latin_name = $_POST['latin_name'];

        $stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT common_name, variety_name, colour, season_of_interest, hardiness, situation, soil_type, price, stock_level, fragrance, ultimate_height FROM rosename WHERE latin_name = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $latin_name);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            /* fetch associative array */
            echo "<form><input type='text' value='" . $result["common_name"] . "' name='common_name' />";
            echo "<input type='text' value='" . $result["variety_name"] . "' name='variety_name' /></form>";
            // i no I need to add more here..
            exit;
        }

        //put out the footer and then stop the rest of the script from running, so we don't display the rest of the form (this is after the form has been submitted)
        require_once('footer.php');
        exit;
    }

    //if we do have errors, show the error message
    else {
        echo "<p>".$error_msg."</p>";
    }}

}
```

Corrections on brackets and bind_param().

Comment: Thanks for those corrections. Even though those corrections are correct, it still does nothing after I click the submit button.

Comment: Does it load the page at least?

Comment: yes the page loads fine and shows the input for latin name. But when you enter in a latin name and click the submit button to retrieve the record, it does nothing, just refreshes the same page

Comment: Maybe has something to do with other pieces of code that you haven't post. This piece of php is in the same file that your form? Could you post the php code previous to `if (!$errors) {`?

Comment: lol were getting there... When I click the submit button now, the form disappears and just shows the green background. I want it to display each field with the retrieved record values for each column

Comment: Does it shows the footer? If it's, then the problem is that this condition is false: `if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {`

Comment: Edited my answer, you were not executing the sql query.

Comment: Thanks, now getting errors saying that row is an undefined variable

Comment: it says the same thing for results aswel

Comment: This is crazy, now says 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array'

Comment: I'm not testing the code, I'm just searching php docs, what I'm pretty sure you can do. I haven't used mysqli and just tried to guide you or at least give you some starting points. I suggest you reading http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php, and look at the syntax. The part of `while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))` will help you.